# parse and print json returned results from controller to callback function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have read everything related on SO, they helped me get this far, I have seen their answers but somehow they could not resolve it completely.

Here is the question:

I return this from a Controller

```
    $data = DB::table('polls')
    ->select('oui')
    ->where('id', '=', 175)
    ->get();
    return( json_encode($data));
```

and this is the part of the JQUERY:

```
       $.post($url, {oui: valor, id: id},function(data){
       $('#yes').text(data);
       //here below another try to print it correctly taken from SO similar questions
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      alert(obj.oui);
```

So, what happens is:

1) `$('#yes').text(data);`

prints correct results but badly formatted, it prints this:

```
[{"oui":500}]
```

and I just want it to print the 500

2) The   `alert(obj.oui);`  prints undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$data` will have the result from the database, so it is printing as `[{"oui":500}]`. I see your query always will return 1 result (guessed this by looking at your where condition on id column, and id is usually unique), so you can do something like below:

```
obj[0].oui
```

This should print 500.

**Why the [0] ??**

Because, the `json_encode()` in php encodes your array `$data` as a json string, and jQuery's `parseJSON()` converts the string to a javascript object, in this case, as you can see the square brackets `[]`, the converted object is an array.

Now, since your database always returns 1 row, the array will have only one element. And, arrays are 0-index based (1st element is at index 0, 2nd at index 1 and so on). So, to get the first and the only data from array, you have to do `obj[0]`. That will give you a javascript object denoted by `{}`. And, to access the `oui` property of the object, you have to use `.` (dot). This `obj[0].oui`.

Cannot be more descriptive I guess. And yes I can read French, studied in high school. :)

Comment: Thank you that was the point! you were very insightful, indeed this is what was happening. It printed out 500, I will give you the right answer in 3 minutes (time that SO requires). Why the [0] ? My query at the end will actually be a SUM of several 'oui' (yes votes in French) corresponding to the differwent id of people. Will then the same answer apply?